# Jenkins UI being slow, and everytime I click, I got some logs

Tags: jenkins

I just noticed that Jenkisn UI is lagging. When I click, it just hang 3 seconds, and proceed to the next screen. Sometime, it took 15~20 seconds, especially, when I try to save pipeline.

Noticed that whenever I navigate around following log comes out.

Can I have some advise?

thank you

```
    23 16:45:52.330+0000 [id=382973]        WARNING        o.j.p.w.cps.CpsFlowExecution#blocksRestart: Not blocking restart due to problem checking running steps in CpsFlowExecution[Owner[scripts/is-dismod-running/21052:scripts/is-dismod-running #21052]]
    l.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timeout waiting for task.
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:259)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:91)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.blocksRestart(CpsFlowExecution.java:950)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun$2.blocksRestart(WorkflowRun.java:398)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun$2.displayCell(WorkflowRun.java:401)
    at hudson.model.Executor.isDisplayCell(Executor.java:668)
    at hudson.model.Computer.getDisplayExecutors(Computer.java:1012)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor106.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.util.PropertyExecutor.execute(PropertyExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.util.introspection.UberspectImpl$VelGetterImpl.invoke(UberspectImpl.java:314)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTArrayAccess.evaluateExpr(ASTArrayAccess.java:185)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTIdentifier.execute(ASTIdentifier.java:75)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReference.execute(ASTReference.java:83)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReference.value(ASTReference.java:57)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.parser.ASTReferenceExpression.value(ASTReferenceExpression.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.jexl.ExpressionImpl.evaluate(ExpressionImpl.java:80)
    at hudson.ExpressionFactory2$JexlExpression.evaluate(ExpressionFactory2.java:74)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$3.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:134)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.TagSupport.invokeBody(TagSupport.java:161)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.ForEachTag.doTag(ForEachTag.java:150)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:100)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.TagSupport.invokeBody(TagSupport.java:161)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.OtherwiseTag.doTag(OtherwiseTag.java:41)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:100)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.TagSupport.invokeBody(TagSupport.java:161)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.ChooseTag.doTag(ChooseTag.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:100)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:120)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:120)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.JellyBuilder.doInvokeMethod(JellyBuilder.java:271)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.Namespace$ProxyImpl.invoke(Namespace.java:92)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy70.executors(Unknown Source)
    at lib.JenkinsTagLib$executors$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at jenkins.widgets.ExecutorsWidget.index.run(index.groovy:5)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.GroovierJellyScript.run(GroovierJellyScript.java:74)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.groovy.GroovierJellyScript.run(GroovierJellyScript.java:62)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.IncludeTag.doTag(IncludeTag.java:147)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.TagSupport.invokeBody(TagSupport.java:161)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.ForEachTag.doTag(ForEachTag.java:150)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$1.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:98)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:120)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyViewScript.run(JellyViewScript.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.IncludeTag.doTag(IncludeTag.java:147)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:100)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$1.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:98)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:100)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:100)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ReallyStaticTagLibrary$1.run(ReallyStaticTagLibrary.java:100)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript$1.run(CallTagLibScript.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.define.InvokeBodyTag.doTag(InvokeBodyTag.java:91)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:120)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.ScriptBlock.run(ScriptBlock.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.tags.core.CoreTagLibrary$2.run(CoreTagLibrary.java:105)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CallTagLibScript.run(CallTagLibScript.java:120)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.CompressTag.doTag(CompressTag.java:44)
    at org.apache.commons.jelly.impl.TagScript.run(TagScript.java:269)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyViewScript.run(JellyViewScript.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:64)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.DefaultScriptInvoker.invokeScript(DefaultScriptInvoker.java:54)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ScriptInvoker.execute(ScriptInvoker.java:56)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.ScriptInvoker.execute(ScriptInvoker.java:43)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Facet.handleIndexRequest(Facet.java:284)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.jelly.JellyFacet.handleIndexRequest(JellyFacet.java:100)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.IndexViewDispatcher.dispatch(IndexViewDispatcher.java:32)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:766)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:898)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:834)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:898)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$4.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:281)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:766)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:898)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:694)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:240)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1633)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
    at jenkins.telemetry.impl.UserLanguages$AcceptLanguageFilter.doFilter(UserLanguages.java:129)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at jenkins.security.ResourceDomainFilter.doFilter(ResourceDomainFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ssegateway.Endpoint$SSEListenChannelFilter.doFilter(Endpoint.java:248)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at com.atlassian.bitbucket.jenkins.internal.applink.oauth.serviceprovider.auth.OAuth1aRequestFilter.doFilter(OAuth1aRequestFilter.java:91)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at io.jenkins.blueocean.ResourceCacheControl.doFilter(ResourceCacheControl.java:134)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at io.jenkins.blueocean.auth.jwt.impl.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:60)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at hudson.plugins.greenballs.GreenBallFilter.doFilter(GreenBallFilter.java:64)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1609)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1609)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1609)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1609)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1609)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1609)
    at jenkins.security.SuspiciousRequestFilter.doFilter(SuspiciousRequestFilter.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1609)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:578)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1612)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1434)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:556)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:773)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:905)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```